# zsh: segmentation fault heroku login

Tags: heroku

I just install heroku cli from the website, and want to log in from termial through
"heroku login"
but I receive this message:
"zsh: segmentation fault  heroku login"
I tried "heroku login -i", too, but it still doesn't work. I also tried to install from the homebrew, but not, either.

I use Mac OS Monterey 12.5 version.

Can anyone help me?